# sympy.Sum error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, sympy

I am programming the following function (in python):

```
def draw_fourier(a, n):
    if len(a) < 2*n + 1:
        return NotImplemented
    else:
        return (1/n) * sy.Sum(a[y] * np.exp(1j * y * t), (y, -n, n))
```

(sy. signifies sympy and np. signifies numpy)
And I get the following error:

```
line 91, in draw_fourier
    return (1/n) * sy.Sum(a[y] * np.exp(1j * y * t), (y, -n, n))
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I previously also got similar errors with sympy.Sum - I have yet to actually successfully use it, so I am curious as to what I am doing wrong, or understanding wrong about the function. I would like it to evaluate the sum for $y$ from $-n$ to $n$. a is a list and n is an (positive) integer. The reason I am using sympy is that 't' is a symbol, which I would like to assign a value to later.

Many thanks,
Hugo

Comment: Where are you calling `draw_fourier()`?

Comment: @GodisOne I am defining a list using a 'for' loop, and each element in that list is a 'draw_fourier()' "output" so to speak.

Comment: I think the problem is that 'y' is also a symbol and a symbol cannot be the index of a list.

Comment: what is `a`?  array?

Comment: If `a` was actually a `list`, you'd have gotten a different error.  `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Symbol`.  The mention of list or array in the error should be a strong clue as to where the problem lies.

Comment: Also you can't use symbol `s` in `np.exp`.   `1j * y * t` is of type `sy.Mul`.  Mixing numpy and sympy is a bad idea - unless you have a good knowledge of both.

Comment: Why are you using `np.exp` instead of `sy.exp`?

Comment: Since `y` can be a negative integer, is it the desired result that you're using a negative index on array `a`? Is `a` a python list, numpy array, or sympy matrix?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `sy.Sum(expression, (dummy_variable, start, end))` your `dummy_variable` (in this case `y`) is a symbol. The error is that `y` cannot be an index of the list `a` because it is not a valid type for an index, as it is a symbol.

A simple way to write that symbolic summation where the coefficient in `a` changes in every term could be:

```
summation=0 #some initialization
for i in range(-n,n):
    summation+=a[i]*sy.exp(1j*i*t)
summation=(1/n)*summation #final expression
```